# What is web services?

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

Can anybody explain what is "web services" and how we use it with proper examples?

Comment: please search these type of stuffs in google.

Comment: This topic is little bit confused for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can view 
[web-service-vs-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111243/web-service-vs-web-application) to understand better.

And if you want to explore more about it you can visit 
[soap-or-rest-for-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595/soap-or-rest-for-web-services).

Answer (score 1):

In sample words "A web service is a way or approach for communication between two machines".
Its a communication channel between two remote machine , that can understand the way how they communicate with each other and send / receive data to each other over the web.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you want to access your database but you can not open your database to internet. At that time you need the web services. You can write a service what language you want it is not matter. This service (actually it is just a method) will connect your database and it will take some data what you need and than it will open the datas to internet. You will access this datas with this service. In this way you take just your need datas at the same time your database is still safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp

A web service is the AWS (Amazon Web Services). You can see each of them here: http://aws.amazon.com/en/products/

**Examples:**

- Amazon EC2: cloud computing.
- Amazon E3: storage service;

[...]

Good studies.

Answer (score 0):

Web Service is mainly concentrating on B2B Communication. If we take the example of web application merchant looses its control but in the web services consumer is having its control over the application. For example in any banking application, if the merchant wants that everything should happen at its side without loosing its control like for the transaction the control should not go to the payment gateway instead in the backhand merchant hits the payment gateway transaction logic and get the results and display it on its own website so the mentioned situation is the best suitable.