# Difference between api and web service?

Tags: web-services, api-design

In many questions, people have explained the difference between an API and a web service. I know it's a means of communication between service provider and service consumer, but both look the same as serving to me: the consumer sends a request and gets a response in return from the provider.

1. If that is so what is it that really makes them different?
2. Why do we have two different terms, both *web service* and *API*?

Answer (score 4):

All answers above are perfectly fine, consider one short note -

API = connecting with some other code (internal [without network] or external [with network] )

API over HTTP = Web Service

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a great answer from user Buh Buh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111243/web-service-vs-web-application) on April 12, '13:

> At a low level web applications and web services are kinda the same
>   thing. They both operatate over http(s). SOAP is just a well defined
>   version of XML. REST is kinda just HTTP. If you wanted to, you could
>   make a web application look like web services and visa versa.
>
> The main difference would be internal development options based on the
>   platform you are using. If, for example, you are using Visual Studio
>   then adding a WCF Service Application will give you a project which is
>   by default geared towards WCF. But choosing any other application type
>   won't stop you from adding Web Services.
>
> Using SOAP is generally a better option than plain old xml for these
>   reasons:
>
> - Your users will be expecting it, and are likely to know how to read it
>     already.
> - Your users' development environments will likely know all
>     about SOAP and be able to interpret it out of the box. (If you provide
>     a WSDL file then many users will be able to use a script to generate
>     your classes in seconds.)
> - Your messages are more likely to be well
>     defined. I am working on a project at the moment where the other side
>     have defined their own random XML structure and it is a nightmare to
>     work with. I never really know what to expect, and there is little
>     consistency between their different message types. At least if they
>     had agreed to conform to SOAP then I might have had a much easier time
>     interpreting their messages.

Answer (score 3):

An [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is not necessarily web-based. It's really just a specification of *how to talk* to someone else's work using a programming language. A [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), on the other hand, is one example of *someone else's work* which a program will talk to using an API.

In the case of a web service, an API might specify how to communicate over the web to the service, in order to use it. Frequently, however, the communication protocol for a service will not be described directly. Instead, the API will be a specification of how to use a client library provided by the service author. A good example of both of these is the Google Maps API. Google provides both a specification of how to request data from their service via [HTTP](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) (a web service API) and a client library in [Javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) which can be used to request the same thing.

But this is not the only possible use of the term *API*. jQuery (which is a Javascript library, but not a remote web service) also refers to its documentation as [API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/). Similarly, the Wikipedia page on [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) gives the example of the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard for operating systems.

In short, an API is a specification, while a web service is one example of a system which can be documented with an API.

Answer (score 1):

An API need not be a Web Service at all (Although in the web world it is more likely that an API is a web service). An API could be for Hardware for Database connectivity etc.